# How to filter Date Columns and store them as numbers in Data Frames using Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataframe (dateds1) which looks like below,

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|DateofBirth|JoiningDate|      Contract Date|        ReleaseDate|
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1995/09/16| 2008/09/09|2009-02-09 00:00:00|2017-09-09 00:00:00|
| 1994/09/20| 2008/09/10|1999-05-05 00:00:00|2016-09-30 00:00:00|
| 1993/09/24| 2016/06/29|2003-12-07 00:00:00|2028-02-13 00:00:00|
| 1992/09/28| 2007/06/24|2004-06-05 00:00:00|2019-09-24 00:00:00|
| 1991/10/03| 2011/07/07|2011-07-07 00:00:00|2020-03-30 00:00:00|
| 1990/10/07| 2009/02/09|2009-02-09 00:00:00|2011-03-13 00:00:00|
| 1989/10/11| 1999/05/05|1999-05-05 00:00:00|2021-03-13 00:00:00|
```

I need help in filtering it out, my output should look like below,

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|DateofBirth|JoiningDate|      Contract Date|        ReleaseDate|
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 19950916  | 20080909  |20090209           |20170909           |
| 19940920  | 20080910  |19990505           |20160930           |
| 19930924  | 20160629  |20031207           |20280213           |
| 19920928  | 20070624  |20040605           |20190924           |
| 19911003  | 20110707  |20110707           |20200330           |
| 19901007  | 20090209  |20090209           |20110313           |
| 19891011  | 19990505  |19990505           |20210313           |
```

I tried using filter, but I was able to filter only for either of the one case, when the dates are in YYYY/MM/DD or YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 format and number of columns are fixed. Can someone please help me in figuring it out for both the formats and when the number of columns are **dynamic**(They might be increasing or decreasing).
They should be converted from Date Datatype to Integers or Long in this format YYYYMMDD.

**Note: The records in this Dataframe or either in YYYY/MM/DD or YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 format.** 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that conversion dynamically you'll have to iterate through all columns and perform different operations depending on the column type.

Here's an example:

```
import java.sql.Date
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import java.sql.Timestamp

val originalDf = Seq(
    (Timestamp.valueOf("2016-09-30 03:04:00"),Date.valueOf("2016-09-30")),
    (Timestamp.valueOf("2016-07-30 00:00:00"),Date.valueOf("2016-10-30"))
).toDF("ts_value","date_value")
```

Original table details:

```
> originalDf.show
+-------------------+----------+
|           ts_value|date_value|
+-------------------+----------+
|2016-09-30 03:04:00|2016-09-30|
|2016-07-30 00:00:00|2016-10-30|
+-------------------+----------+

> originalDf.printSchema
root
 |-- ts_value: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- date_value: date (nullable = true)
```

Example of conversion operation:

```
val newDf = originalDf.columns.foldLeft(originalDf)((df, name) => {
    val data_type = df.schema(name).dataType
    if(data_type == DateType)
        df.withColumn(name, date_format(col(name), "yyyyMMdd").cast(IntegerType))
    else if(data_type == TimestampType)
        df.withColumn(name, year(col(name))*10000 + month(col(name))*100 + dayofmonth(col(name)))
    else
        df
})
```

New table details:

```
newDf.show
+--------+----------+
|ts_value|date_value|
+--------+----------+
|20160930|  20160930|
|20160730|  20161030|
+--------+----------+
newDf.printSchema
root
 |-- ts_value: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- date_value: integer (nullable = true)
```

If you don't want to perform this operation in all columns you can manually specify the columns by changing

```
val newDf = originalDf.columns.foldLeft ...
```

to

```
val newDf = Seq("col1_name","col2_name", ... ).foldLeft ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andre..you are the best. I have a small doubt what if the date is 2019/03/03, it takes it as a string instead of Date Type. What kind of condition can be included in else if for this kind of date format(YYYY/MM/DD). Can you please suggest anything on this.

Comment: No worries Andre, I figured it out..I did this " else if (data_type == StringType)
     df.withColumn(name, concat(substring(col(name),1,4),substring(col(name),6,2), substring(col(name),9,2) )) "